# como puedo crear un archivo que llleve de nombre fecha-hora.log

Tags: python, variables, ejecutar

```
import datetime
fecha = str(datetime.datetime.now())+str('test.log')
print (fecha)--> 2018-10-30 09:18:29.606405test.log
```

¿Porque en consola de python me ejecuta y me saca el nombre que quiero y al ejecutarlo en el codigo no?

la linea en la que uso la fecha es esta

```
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename = fecha, 
when='m', interval=1, backupCount=5)
```

En vez de interpretar el valos de la variable el archivo me lo llama fecha
¿Alguien podría darme alguna solución o pista?

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo que no te funciona? De buenas a primeras, pareciera que el error que tienes es que hay que "escapar" el nombre del archivo (los dos puntos que tiene la hora, habitualmente dan problemas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he podido reproducir lo que mencionas, pero definitivamente el nombre que usas, como ya te han comentado, no es un nombre válido para muchos sistemas operativos. En Linux es cierto, debería funcionarte, en Windows definitivamente no, deberías obtener un excepción del tipo `OSError`.

Te recomiendo que le des a la fecha un formato compatible con todos los sistemas operativos, preferentemente quitando caracteres problemáticos como `:` los guiones y los espacios. Puedes usar `strftime()` de la siguiente forma:

```
LOG_FILENAME = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%Stest.log")
print(LOG_FILENAME)

20181030_143434test.log
```

Por otro lado usar una fecha como nombre de archivo en un `TimedRotatingFileHandler` es poco habitual, en estos casos se estila más dar un nombre genérico al log (sin fecha), y el handler se encargara de ir renovando los archivos a medida que pasa el tiempo y renombrando los archivos con la fecha de rotación.

Un ejemplo funcional podría ser:

```
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers
import datetime
import time

LOG_FILENAME = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%Stest.log")

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Definimos el handler a efectos de prueba, el intervalo lo dejamos en 1 seg
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename = LOG_FILENAME, 
                                                    when='s', interval=1, backupCount=5)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)

# Logeamos unos cuantos mensajes de prueba
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)  
    my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)

# Vemos que archivos creo el loop anterior
logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)
for filename in logfiles:
    print(filename)

20181030_113112test.log
20181030_113112test.log.2018-10-30_11-31-17
20181030_113112test.log.2018-10-30_11-31-18
20181030_113112test.log.2018-10-30_11-31-19
20181030_113112test.log.2018-10-30_11-31-20
20181030_113112test.log.2018-10-30_11-31-21
```

El último ciclo nos listará los nombres de los archivo log generados, la rotación esta definida en 1 segundo para notar justamente este comportamiento. Puedes ver que el nombre base del archivo se mantiene y cada segundo aproximadamente se generaría una rotación del log. El nombre original `20181030_113112test.log` siempre representa el log actual.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado a la perfección, hice unas últimas modificaciones y quedo todo perfecto.